# How to share a Pages document between macOS High Sierra & OSX El Capitan without going to iCloud on the browser?

Tags: icloud, macos, high-sierra, pages, sharing

I'm running macOS High Sierra. My wife is on a computer that only supports OS X El Capitan.
She writes a document on Pages.
How does she collaborate with me, or I with her, so that neither of us are bumped to iCloud.com.

I would like it so that she could write a document, and share it with me in such a way that we both see how I tweak it, or that I write a document and share it with her so that we both can see and edit it. But without being bumped into iCloud.

I'm yet to figure out how to do it. I've tried sharing via iMessage, or sharing via email.. what am I missing?

Comment: Are you wanting live collaboration, like in Google Docs, or are you happy with being able to track changes, and email revisions back and forth manually?

Comment: @daviewales i would prefer live collaboration, if possible. It is good to see what she adjusts and for her to see what I adjust as we work on it together.

Comment: It looks like live collaboration is only possible with newer systems. Have you considered using Google Docs for the live part, then moving it to Pages for the final polish?

Comment: Is it possible for your wife to upgrade to Sierra? This support article lists the minimum requirements for what you are trying to do: https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT206181

Comment: @daviewales it is not possible for her to upgrade to Sierra, she's running on a mid-2009 MacBookPro which can only run OS X El Capitan.

Comment: @daviewales ok thanks! I'll try and get her upgraded as soon as possible :)

Comment: @daviewales yep i guess i'll move her to google docs and that way it'll work even on her machine. thanks for the handholding + advice!